# An error has occurred. Retry later.If the problems persists, contact the system administrator. - KNOWAGE

Tags: configuration, tomcat9, fiware-knowage

having trouble running generic report after upgrading tomcat version from 7.0.50 to version 9.0.38.

**Knowage version : 6.4.4** 
**OS : CentOS 7** 
**Tomcat version : 9.0.38**

**Error from log file :**

> 13 Oct 2020 16:02:27,173 ERROR
> it.eng.spagobi.utilities.filters.SpagoBIAccessFilter.doFilter:194
> -SpagoBIAccessFilter:doFilter ServletException!! javax.servlet.ServletException: Message: Error occured while
> retrieving user profile of user
> [eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiYmlhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTYwMjYxMjEzN30.gcHxPvJDfbZCLh6bw1EVuPM3bUnY0xEvgz2KJgE77oA]
> from service [Security Service] at endpoint
> [https://sample:443/knowage/services/SecurityService]; Cause: ; nested
> exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
> at it.eng.spagobi.utilities.filters.SpagoBIAccessFilter.doFilter(SpagoBIAccessFilter.java:167)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at it.eng.spagobi.utilities.filters.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:54)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 13 Oct 2020 16:02:27,173 ERROR
> it.eng.spagobi.utilities.filters.SpagoBIAccessFilter.doFilter:194 -
> SpagoBIAccessFilter:doFilter ServletException!!
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Message: Error occured while
> retrieving user profile of user
> [eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiYmlhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTYwMjYxMjEzN30.gcHxPvJDfbZCLh6bw1EVuPM3bUnY0xEvgz2KJgE77oA]
> from service [Security Service] at endpoint
> [https://sample:443/knowage/services/SecurityService]; Cause: ; nested
> exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version

**Error From Knowage Server :**

```
 An error has occurred. Retry later.If the problems persists, contact the system administrator.
```

Note : not yet upgrading knowage version for other issue isolation.

Any Idea how to fix ? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution for this

Found out that my TLS versionning is incorrect. Changed it to protocols=TLSv1.2 , restart tomcat and clear cache. Reports are now working.

Comment: Hi Sam, I experienced the same thing, how do to fix it.

Best regards, Anton